# decrease load time of form with many list boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, listbox

I have a form that can have as many as 400 list boxes, each list box can have as many as 900 items.  The form is created using a foreach loop:

```
foreach(var i in Model)
{
    var selectList = Model.OrderBy(m => m.Name)
                        .Select(m => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = m.Name,
                            Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                        }).ToList();
    @Html.ListBox(i+"ListBox", selectList, new { @class = "multiselect", size = "12", multiple = "true", })
}
```

when this loop is removed the page loads 4x faster.

Is there anyway to do this that will reduce the load time of the page?

Comment: `I have a form that can have as many as 400 list boxes, each list box can have as many as 900 items.` - OMHG. May God have mercy on the soul of the users of this application. I am sure it's not their fault, but why make them suffer so much? Did they deserve this?

Comment: Not an answer, but really 400 listboxes on a single form? Something has gone out of control here.

Comment: 400 listboxes and 900 item per listbox... consider redesign.. p.s. did you ever heared of usability

Comment: Please include a screenshot I want to see this!

Comment: I'm curious as to what the actual payload is of the page being returned. It has got to be monumental. Why do you need 400 list boxes in a single form? I cannot see any valid reason. Perhaps a little more info on what exactly you're trying to do would help. If you seriously require that much input in a single form I would break it up into a wizard, and save after each step. I would NEVER, EVER and I mean EVER fill out a form that big.

Comment: LOL i agree, and we have tried to talk to the client, they are unwilling to budge, all list boxes do not need to be filled out, its up to the user which are filled, but displaying them dynamically is also out of the question...